# Can you pipe non-text data from a python script via PowerShell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, pipe, powershell-3.0

I am fairly familiar with bash and know how to some basic scripting stuff involving pipes, and use them as a 'back end' to run python scripts in sequence.

However, for a new project I've been tasked with I can only use PowerShell. I've found that I can rewrite my previous shell scripts fine, buta I hear that you can pipe non-text data in PowerShell too.

My question is:

Is it possible to pipe non-text output (primarily a pandas dataframe) from a python script into another python script via PowerShell?

Something similar to:

```
script1.py | script2.py
```

If so, what are the logistics in regards to the python script? I.E can you still return to `sys.stdout`?

**EDIT**:

To better explain to usecase to be in line with the comments I've received.

I have two python scripts, `test1.py`:

```
#test1.py
import pandas as pd
import sys


def main():
    columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    data = [
        ['hello', 0,  3.14],
        ['world', 1,  2.71],
        ['foo',   2,  0.577],
        ['bar',   3,  1.61]

    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main().to_csv(sys.stdout, index_label=False)
```

and `test2.py`:

```
#test2.py
import pandas as pd
import sys


def main():
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
    print(df.dtypes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm using PowerShell to do some automation, and need to pipe the output of one script to the other; `python test1.py | python test2.py` works perfectly fine.

My question is, I have heard that you can pipe non-text data in PowerShell, which you can't do in Bash (I think), so is it possible to pipe the Dataframe as it is? (without having to convert to a CSV or some other string encoding)

Comment: why on EARTH would you need to do that? [*frown*] you are running 2 python instances one-after-the-other ... so just use python coding methods to get info from one to the other. powershell has no place whatsoever in the situation.

Comment: Perhaps the author only has control of one or none of the python source files. Perhaps the process has worked on linux for years and they want to port it to windows without rewriting the logic. It seems like a reasonable question, though I do encourage the original poster to show more of what they have attempted so far.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey We are using shell scripts as a backend to orchestrate many scripts (not just python) in a small ML platform where tooling options are limited. So, although I agree with you that it doesn't _NEED_ to be done this way at all, I am exploring what can be done this way.

Comment: @JonSG you hit the nail on the head - I do not have control of all the scripts, just the output. The process was originally built in bash, but there is no WSL/Bash for windows available in the workspace.

Comment: It looks like powershell may not support piping binary data : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708859/output-binary-data-on-powershell-pipeline

Comment: thank all of y'all for the feedback. [*grin*] it still seems odd to need to feed one python script output to a 2nd one ... but not use python to do that.

Comment: @JonSG this link confuses me, but that's probably because I am a mere Python dev and not knowledgeable in C (or much of PowerShell).

Comment: @Lee_Dailey no worries!

Comment: in the guts of that post there is some discussion about powershell `|` always doing an encoding and thus making piping of binary data impossible. I don't know enough powershell to really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

- **[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.4+** now ***does* support raw byte handling with external programs** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).
- The **following therefore applies only to *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core) v7.3-***

---

**In PowerShell versions up to v7.3.x, there is *no* support for *binary data* (raw bytes) in PowerShell's pipeline**.

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68488098/45375) for more information.

The **workaround** is to **use `cmd.exe /c`** (on Windows; on Unix-like platforms, use `/bin/sh -c`):

```
cmd /c 'script1.py | script2.py'
```

Note:

- If you additionally want to ***capture* the raw byte output *in PowerShell***:

  - Include an *output redirection* (`>`)in the `cmd /c` command string; e.g.:

    ```
    cmd /c 'script1.py | script2.py > out.bin'
    ```
  - Then read that file *as bytes* with `Get-Content -Encoding Byte` (Windows PowerShell) / `Get-Content -AsByteStream` (PowerShell (Core) 7+)
- If, by contrast, you want **to capture the output from the `cmd /c` call *as text* (strings)**:

  - You have to (temporarily) **set `[Console]::OutputEncoding`** to the system's active **ANSI code page**, which Python defaults to when outputting to something other than the *console* (deviating from the usual behavior of using the active *OEM* code page).

    - In *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to 5.1), you can to this as follows:

      ```
      [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
      ```

      - Note: In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, more work is needed:

        ```
        [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([int] (Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage ACP))
        ```
  - Note that you can also **configure Python to output UTF-8 by default**: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67778646/45375); in that case, use the following:

    ```
     [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
    ```
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for more information.